# Google Sheets: I'd like a formula that will lookup an ID in a table, then count the number of non-blank cells in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For example, I would like the formula to lookup the UID 4119.502914 and count the number of non-blank cells in the range C2:G2. The result would be 0 in this case.

Here is the data table:

| UID | Active since | Level A1 result | Level A2 result | Level B1 result | Level B2 result | Level C1 result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4119.502914 | 16/03/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32502.84434 | 16/03/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3439.094252 | 21/03/2022 | B |  |  |  |  |
| 78344.29029 | 05/08/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 82511.53052 | 24/05/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 40939.00908 | 16/03/2022 | A | A+ | A | A+ |  |
| 19481.28071 | 30/03/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6259.532774 | 04/08/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13352.59697 | 04/08/2022 | A+ | C |  |  |  |
| 54786.31186 | 18/03/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 82548.2726 | 16/03/2022 | B+ | B+ |  |  |  |
| 50125.47835 | 04/08/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 27984.35676 | 04/08/2022 | A |  |  |  |  |

Here is the expected result:

| UID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 4119.502914 | 0 |
| 32502.84434 | 0 |
| 3439.094252 | 1 |
| 78344.29029 | 0 |
| 82511.53052 | 0 |
| 40939.00908 | 4 |
| 19481.28071 | 0 |
| 6259.532774 | 0 |
| 13352.59697 | 2 |
| 54786.31186 | 0 |
| 82548.2726 | 2 |
| 50125.47835 | 0 |
| 27984.35676 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try the following formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX($C$3:$G$15,XMATCH(H3,$A$3:$A$15)),"<>")
```

[image]